# Single thread run 6 times slower than 2 thread run

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to optimize, and also improve features of, the [Makefile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/Makefile) of the [Linux man-pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/).

Before, it only had `make uninstall` and `make install`, both of which ran a small shell script that run in a single thread, which took between 5 and 10 seconds on my laptop (`i7-8850H` 6C/12T).

I added the possibility of installing only some section (e.g., `man3/` only) with `make install-man3`.

That also made it possible to install everything in parallel, thus allowing `make -j install`.

Using multiple threads improves times drastically, but now using a single thread to install also drastically increases the time to install.  For comparison, these are the times on my laptop (`make` does the same as `make uninstall && make install`):

Old Makefile:

```
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make >/dev/null
    
real    0m7.509s
user    0m5.269s
sys     0m2.614s
```

The times with the old makefile, varied a lot, between 5 and 10 seconds.

New Makefile:

```
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make >/dev/null
    
real    0m27.883s
user    0m18.257s
sys     0m10.735s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j2 >/dev/null

real    0m4.636s
user    0m8.514s
sys     0m1.475s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j4 >/dev/null
    
real    0m2.582s
user    0m8.400s
sys     0m1.369s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j >/dev/null
    
real    0m2.071s
user    0m9.203s
sys     0m1.704s
```

These new times are very consistent.

If I run `make -n` I get very small times, so I think it's not make overhead, but actual work being done:

```
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -n >/dev/null

real    0m1.086s
user    0m1.116s
sys     0m0.117s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -nj >/dev/null

real    0m0.652s
user    0m1.269s
sys     0m0.146s
```

The current (new) Makefile I'm working with is (after removing some uninteresting parts):

`Makefile`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash -Eeuo pipefail

MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
MAKEFLAGS += --silent

ROOTDIR := $(CURDIR)

DESTDIR :=
prefix := /usr/local
datarootdir := $(prefix)/share
MANDIR := $(ROOTDIR)
mandir := $(datarootdir)/man
MAN1DIR := $(MANDIR)/man1
MAN2DIR := $(MANDIR)/man2
MAN3DIR := $(MANDIR)/man3
MAN4DIR := $(MANDIR)/man4
MAN5DIR := $(MANDIR)/man5
MAN6DIR := $(MANDIR)/man6
MAN7DIR := $(MANDIR)/man7
MAN8DIR := $(MANDIR)/man8
man1dir := $(mandir)/man1
man2dir := $(mandir)/man2
man3dir := $(mandir)/man3
man4dir := $(mandir)/man4
man5dir := $(mandir)/man5
man6dir := $(mandir)/man6
man7dir := $(mandir)/man7
man8dir := $(mandir)/man8
man1ext := \.1
man2ext := \.2
man3ext := \.3
man4ext := \.4
man5ext := \.5
man6ext := \.6
man7ext := \.7
man8ext := \.8

INSTALL := install
INSTALL_DATA := $(INSTALL) -m 644
INSTALL_DIR := $(INSTALL) -m 755 -d
RM := rm -f
RMDIR := rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty


.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) uninstall;
    $(MAKE) install;


%/:
    @echo ' INSTALL $@';
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $@;


.PHONY: install
install: install-man

.PHONY: uninstall remove
uninstall remove: uninstall-man

################################################################################
# man

MAN1PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN1DIR) -type f | grep '$(man1ext)$$' | sort)
MAN2PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN2DIR) -type f | grep '$(man2ext)$$' | sort)
MAN3PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN3DIR) -type f | grep '$(man3ext)$$' | sort)
MAN4PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN4DIR) -type f | grep '$(man4ext)$$' | sort)
MAN5PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN5DIR) -type f | grep '$(man5ext)$$' | sort)
MAN6PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN6DIR) -type f | grep '$(man6ext)$$' | sort)
MAN7PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN7DIR) -type f | grep '$(man7ext)$$' | sort)
MAN8PAGES := $(shell find $(MAN8DIR) -type f | grep '$(man8ext)$$' | sort)

man1pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN1PAGES))
man2pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN2PAGES))
man3pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN3PAGES))
man4pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN4PAGES))
man5pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN5PAGES))
man6pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN6PAGES))
man7pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN7PAGES))
man8pages := $(patsubst $(MANDIR)/%,$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%,$(MAN8PAGES))
manpages  := $(man1pages) \
             $(man2pages) \
             $(man3pages) \
             $(man4pages) \
             $(man5pages) \
             $(man6pages) \
             $(man7pages) \
             $(man8pages)

$(manpages): $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%: $(MANDIR)/%
    @echo ' INSTALL $@';
    $(INSTALL_DATA) -T '$(MANDIR)/$*' '$@';


INSTALL_MANn := install-man1 \
                install-man2 \
                install-man3 \
                install-man4 \
                install-man5 \
                install-man6 \
                install-man7 \
                install-man8

.PHONY: $(INSTALL_MANn)
$(INSTALL_MANn): install-%: | installdirs-%
    $(MAKE) '_install-$*';

.PHONY: install-man
install-man: $(INSTALL_MANn)
    @:;

.PHONY: _install-man1
_install-man1: $(man1pages)
.PHONY: _install-man2
_install-man2: $(man2pages)
.PHONY: _install-man3
_install-man3: $(man3pages)
.PHONY: _install-man4
_install-man4: $(man4pages)
.PHONY: _install-man5
_install-man5: $(man5pages)
.PHONY: _install-man6
_install-man6: $(man6pages)
.PHONY: _install-man7
_install-man7: $(man7pages)
.PHONY: _install-man8
_install-man8: $(man8pages)


INSTALLDIRS_MANn := installdirs-man1 \
                    installdirs-man2 \
                    installdirs-man3 \
                    installdirs-man4 \
                    installdirs-man5 \
                    installdirs-man6 \
                    installdirs-man7 \
                    installdirs-man8

.PHONY: $(INSTALLDIRS_MANn)
$(INSTALLDIRS_MANn): installdirs-%: $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/%/ | installdirs-man
    @:;

.PHONY: installdirs-man
installdirs-man: $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/
    @:;


uninstall_man1pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man1pages)))
uninstall_man2pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man2pages)))
uninstall_man3pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man3pages)))
uninstall_man4pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man4pages)))
uninstall_man5pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man5pages)))
uninstall_man6pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man6pages)))
uninstall_man7pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man7pages)))
uninstall_man8pages := $(addprefix uninstall-,$(wildcard $(man8pages)))
uninstall_manpages  := $(uninstall_man1pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man2pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man3pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man4pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man5pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man6pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man7pages) \
                       $(uninstall_man8pages)

.PHONY: $(uninstall_manpages)
$(uninstall_manpages): uninstall-%:
    @echo ' RM  $*';
    $(RM) '$*';


UNINSTALL_MANn := uninstall-man1 \
                  uninstall-man2 \
                  uninstall-man3 \
                  uninstall-man4 \
                  uninstall-man5 \
                  uninstall-man6 \
                  uninstall-man7 \
                  uninstall-man8

uninstall-man1: $(uninstall_man1pages)
uninstall-man2: $(uninstall_man2pages)
uninstall-man3: $(uninstall_man3pages)
uninstall-man4: $(uninstall_man4pages)
uninstall-man5: $(uninstall_man5pages)
uninstall-man6: $(uninstall_man6pages)
uninstall-man7: $(uninstall_man7pages)
uninstall-man8: $(uninstall_man8pages)

.PHONY: $(UNINSTALL_MANn)
$(UNINSTALL_MANn): uninstall-%:
    @echo ' RMDIR   $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$*/';
    $(RMDIR) '$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$*/' 2>/dev/null ||:;

.PHONY: uninstall-man
uninstall-man: $(UNINSTALL_MANn)
    @echo ' RMDIR   $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/';
    $(RMDIR) '$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/' ||:;
```

My question is:

Why is it so slow to run it in a single thread?  6 times slower than 2 threads??

---

**EDIT:**  Show `--trace`

```
Makefile:54: target 'all' does not exist
make uninstall;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man1' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man1/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man1/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man1/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man2' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man2/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man2/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man2/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man3' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man3/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man3/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man3/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man4' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man4/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man4/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man4/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man5' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man5/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man5/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man5/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man6' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man6/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man6/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man6/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man7' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man7/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man7/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man7/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8';
...XXX...
Makefile:176: target 'uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8' does not exist
echo '  RM  /usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8';
    RM  /usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8
rm -f '/usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8';
Makefile:200: update target 'uninstall-man8' due to: uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8 ...XXX... uninstall-/usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man8/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/man8/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/man8/' 2>/dev/null ||:;
Makefile:205: update target 'uninstall-man' due to: uninstall-man1 uninstall-man2 uninstall-man3 uninstall-man4 uninstall-man5 uninstall-man6 uninstall-man7 uninstall-man8
echo '  RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/';
    RMDIR   /usr/local/share/man/
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty '/usr/local/share/man/' ||:;
make install;
Makefile:154: update target 'installdirs-man' due to: /usr/local/share/man/
:;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man1' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man1/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man1' does not exist
make '_install-man1';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1' '/usr/local/share/man/man1/getent.1';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1' '/usr/local/share/man/man1/time.1';
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man2' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man2/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man2' does not exist
make '_install-man2';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2' '/usr/local/share/man/man2/accept.2';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2' '/usr/local/share/man/man2/writev.2';
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man3' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man3/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man3' does not exist
make '_install-man3';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man3/a64l.3
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man3/a64l.3' '/usr/local/share/man/man3/a64l.3';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man3/ynl.3
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man3/ynl.3' '/usr/local/share/man/man3/ynl.3';
Makefile:59: target '/usr/local/share/man/man4/' does not exist
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man4/;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man4' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man4/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man4' does not exist
make '_install-man4';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man4/cciss.4
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man4/cciss.4' '/usr/local/share/man/man4/cciss.4';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man4/zero.4
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man4/zero.4' '/usr/local/share/man/man4/zero.4';
Makefile:59: target '/usr/local/share/man/man5/' does not exist
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man5/;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man5' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man5/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man5' does not exist
make '_install-man5';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5' '/usr/local/share/man/man5/acct.5';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man5/wtmp.5
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man5/wtmp.5' '/usr/local/share/man/man5/wtmp.5';
Makefile:59: target '/usr/local/share/man/man6/' does not exist
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man6/';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man6/
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man6/;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man6' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man6/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man6' does not exist
make '_install-man6';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man6/intro.6
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man6/intro.6' '/usr/local/share/man/man6/intro.6';
Makefile:59: target '/usr/local/share/man/man7/' does not exist
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man7/;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man7' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man7/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man7' does not exist
make '_install-man7';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7' '/usr/local/share/man/man7/address_families.7';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7' '/usr/local/share/man/man7/xattr.7';
Makefile:59: target '/usr/local/share/man/man8/' does not exist
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/
install -m 755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man8/;
Makefile:150: update target 'installdirs-man8' due to: /usr/local/share/man/man8/
:;
Makefile:115: target 'install-man8' does not exist
make '_install-man8';
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man8/iconvconfig.8
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man8/iconvconfig.8' '/usr/local/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8';
...XXX...
Makefile:100: update target '/usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8' due to: /home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man8/zic.8
echo '  INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8';
    INSTALL /usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8
install -m 644 -T '/home/user/src/linux/man-pages/man8/zic.8' '/usr/local/share/man/man8/zic.8';
Makefile:119: update target 'install-man' due to: install-man1 install-man2 install-man3 install-man4 install-man5 install-man6 install-man7 install-man8
:;
```

---

**EDIT:** Remove `echo` lines

I removed `echo` lines, and got a very important improvement (around 30% faster in both single- and multi-threaded mode):

```
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make >/dev/null

real    0m20.190s
user    0m11.629s
sys     0m7.177s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j2 >/dev/null

real    0m2.917s
user    0m5.469s
sys     0m1.046s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j >/dev/null

real    0m1.434s
user    0m5.906s
sys     0m1.170s
```

**EDIT:**  Remove actual work lines

```
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make >/dev/null

real    0m7.260s
user    0m5.445s
sys 0m2.110s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j2 >/dev/null

real    0m1.754s
user    0m2.798s
sys 0m0.411s
~/src/linux/man-pages$ time sudo make -j >/dev/null

real    0m1.229s
user    0m3.059s
sys 0m0.402s
```

If instead of the `echo` lines, I remove the lines that do the actual work, I get the rest of the improvement.

It looks like most of the time is actually happening at work, but then how does it improve so much by using `-j2`?  Maybe I'm keeping the cache hot?

Comment: I can't explain the size of the difference in performance.  I recommend you use facilities like the `--trace` option to see if one instance is doing a lot more work than the other.

Comment: Your code looks very IObound. So I guess performance does not depend on the CPU power used, but which part of your disk are in the cache. Usually calling install with -j does not make sense (unless you install into a RAMdrive). If you want to optimize your code, don't call find 6 times. Store the result in a variable and grep the values you are interested in. The sort processes aren't necessary, as it doesn't matter in which order the files are installed. Invoking submake also looks superflous.

Comment: @arved **re: submake:** If I don't invoke a submake, I need to add the dependency of its directory to every file ( `: $(dir $@)` ). That's more correct, but it hurts performance, especially with high `-jN` (around 10% with `-j`).

Comment: @arved **re: find:** Calling find once and then filtering inside make with `$(filter %$(man1ext),$(manpages))` doesn't change performance (at least that I could notice).  But it helps reduce the number of lines in the Makefile, so I'll do this change.

Comment: @arved **re: sort:** `sort` is not necessary, but it doesn't take much time (I didn't notice any time change at all), and it provides a noticable benefit:  I output a line for every installed file, so if they are sorted, that gives an idea of the progress of the install (if we're installing file zyx it's about to finish).

Comment: Since you say that when running with `-n` (which still does all the shell operations) is pretty fast, it's clear that efforts to speed up the "parse the makefile" step won't help: that is a red herring.  But note, I prefer to avoid all the "depend on a directory" stuff as just too complicated.  Why not just add `@mkdir -p $(@D)` into your rules?  Yes, it means you'll be running `mkdir` when not strictly necessary but it simplifies the makefile and the dependency graph.  However, I have no reason to believe it will help performance.

Comment: IMO such a huge slowdown is most likely explained in one of two ways: either there's some pathological thing about your makefile which is causing make to do a ton of work walking the dependency graph (this would certainly have to be related to pattern rules), or one version is actually doing a lot more work (running a lot more commands).  As I said above I don't see why either of these would give such a huge speedup running `-j2`.  You'll simply have to enable tracing and debugging and see if you can suss out what the difference is.  Maybe `ts` will be helpful, not sure.

Comment: @MadScientist I added the log of `sudo make --trace`.  It doesn't show anything that looks weird to me.  I skipped repetitive things with the string `...XXX...`, and left only the first and last page of each dir. There's only one thing that is a bit strange:  It tries to find files for `.PHONY` targets.  But nothing that would make a huge difference with `-j2`

Comment: @MadScientist I also did some tests by removing actual work lines, and it looks like it's those lines that take most of the time.  Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: I am not going to go through all the trace output: that was more a suggestion that YOU should do that and compare the results to see if the slow operation is doing significantly more work or not :).  I do notice you're adding `;` to the ends of all your recipe lines.  That's a very bad idea.  By doing this you're forcing make to use its "slow path" behavior of invoking a shell for every command.  If you leave these off when not necessary, make can choose the "fast path" behavior of invoking your commands directly without a shell.  If it's still slow you can replace `echo` with `$(info ...)`

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "the actual work lines".  Which lines are those?

Comment: @MadScientist **re: "actual work lines":**  I've been a bit inconsistent at that, but I meant invocations of `install`, `rm` and in some contexts `echo`.

Comment: @MadScientist **re: `$(info ...)`:**  Wow!  I didn't know about it!  It cut times by around 40%!!!

Comment: @MadScientist I found out another big overhead was `bash`.  Removing `SHELL := /bin/bash -Eeuo pipefail` (and therefore using `dash` (I'm on Debian)) cut times by half.  I'll make sure I don't need `-o pipefail` and I'll remove that.  There are around 2500 man pages, so calling bash around 10000 times is a bit slow :-)  Why it isn't as slow in parallel, I don't know.

Comment: @MadScientist **re: `;`:**  I didn't notice any improvement by removing all `;`s.

Comment: If you were still using bash then removing the `;` should be a noticeable difference.  With dash less so, although it's still a good idea.  I don't see any pipe operations in your makefile so pipefail doesn't seem needed.

Comment: I should just point out that on many systems, such as RedHat/CentOS, `/bin/sh` is actually a link to bash so you won't save much by removing the `SHELL` assignment on those systems.  Better to avoid invoking a shell altogether.

Comment: These are *processes,* not *threads.*

Comment: @MadScientist re:`;`:  Yes, I'll remove it just in case.

Comment: @MadScientist Oh! I removed the `;`s, and also the quotes `'` (just in case that was also forcing to invoke the shell), and now it I noticed some change.  I dropped another 40~50%.  It's just under 6 s right now on a single *process* ;)  (1.7 s for `-j2` and 1.5 s for `-j`).

Comment: Simple quotes shouldn't matter (I tested it).  make's command parser is just barely smart enough to handle non-complicated quoting :).